# How do I properly add lifetimes to an iterator containing other iterators in Rust?

Tags: rust, iterator, lifetime

I currently have code that looks kind of like this:

```rust
struct People {
    names: Vec<String>,
    ages: Vec<i32>,
}

impl People {
    fn iter_people<'a>(&'a self) -> PeopleIterator<'a> {
        return PeopleIterator {
            names_iterator: Box::new(self.names.iter()),
            ages: Box::new(self.ages.iter()),
        };
    }
}

struct PeopleIterator<'a> {
    names_iterator: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &'a String>>,
    ages: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &'a i32>>,
}

impl<'a> Iterator for PeopleIterator<'a> {
    ...snip...
}
```

I am aware that I should model a person as a `struct Person` and then have a `Vec<Person>` to model people but this is just a simplification of my actual code.

Anyway, the Rust compiler tells me this:

> lifetime may not live long enough
>
> requirement occurs because of the type `PeopleIterator<'_>`, which makes the generic argument `'_` invariant

I have looked at the [suggested link](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html) for subtyping and variance but I need to read it a few more times to actually understand it.

What stumps me is that I would expect both my iterators `self.names.iter()` and `self.ages.iter()` to live as long as `self` and I have declared that `self` should live as long as `PeopleIterator`. However, when I look at the `iter()` function, it does not make this constraint but instead has an anonymous lifetime `'_`. I am guessing this is the problem but I am confused and don't know how to fix it :(

Comment: nit: you can elide the lifetimes of your function to `fn iter_people(&self) -> PeopleIterator<'_> {`

Comment: True, I missed that. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the lifetime of the iterator itself in `Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &'a String>>` is by default bound to be `'static`, but that's not possible for an iterator containing non static references like anything from `&'a self`. The solution is to specify an explicit lifetime bound:

```rust
struct PeopleIterator<'a> {
    names_iterator: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &'a String> + 'a>,
    ages: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &'a i32> + 'a>,
}
```

Personally I'd just use generics instead of static dispatch avoiding some indirection and the whole problem from the beginning:

```rust
impl People {
    fn iter_people(&self) -> PeopleIterator<impl Iterator<Item = &String>, impl Iterator<Item = &i32>> {
        return PeopleIterator {
            names_iterator: self.names.iter(),
            ages: self.ages.iter(),
        };
    }
}

struct PeopleIterator<N, A> {
    names_iterator: N,
    ages: A,
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I am reading up more on lifetimes and I think now I understand it.